# Simple sum in a calculated control MS-access

Tags: ms-access

Trying to get the sum of three fields and enter it in a fourth text box on the same report.  For a particular report,

```
empnose =78
empright=555
empleft= 565
```

The total text box should be 1198

using the expression

```
=Sum([EmpNose] And [EmpRight] And [EmpLeft])
```

the result is -4

using the expression

```
=Sum([EmpNose]+[EmpLeft]+[EmpRight])
```

the result is 226514940

using the expression

```
=([EmpNose]+[EmpLeft]+[EmpRight])
```

the result is 78555565  (the three values concatenated)

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add up the values of the current record only, `Sum()` is wrong, because it sums over all records.

```
=([EmpNose]+[EmpLeft]+[EmpRight])
```

should be correct. If it concatenates the values it seems your fields are text fields instead of numbers?

If you can't change the datatypes to numbers, you can try

```
=(Val([EmpNose]) + Val([EmpLeft]) + Val([EmpRight]))
```

The `Val()` function tries to convert a string to a number.

Comment: The fields were classified as text fields.  As soon as I changed them to numeric, I was able to use   [Empnose]+[empleft]+empright]